# Spark s3 read gives NullPointerException

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark

I am trying to process files from S3 file system. I have exported the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. I have also set the configuration

```
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId","<key>")  
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey","<secret>")
```

**Error:**

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.listStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.listStatus(Globber.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:304)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
```

**build.sbt**  My build.sbt has the following dependencies

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "net.java.dev.jets3t" % "jets3t" % "0.9.3"
```

I use AWS IAM for the access keys. Am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Without more details, I'm going to shoot blindly and say that your URI path  is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug  in some exception handling in `org.apache.hadoop` code shouldn't throw NPE.  Raise a JIRA in the Apache Spark project.